# C++, Valgrind reporting "possibly lost" after char* to std::string "conversion"

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have a class with a constructor like,

```
Foo::Foo(string p) {
    path = p;
}
```

And I use it like this,

```
Foo foo = Foo("/tmp/foo");
```

Sorry for my C++ naivety. I understand that this is creating a `std::string` object implcitly (what's the right terminology for what's going on here?).

This causes Valgrind to complain as such,

```
==28188== 66 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 5
==28188==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28188==    by 0x4EFBF28: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==28188==    by 0x4EFD9B4: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==28188==    by 0x4EFDDDB: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==28188==    by 0x4EC2B05: std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==28188==    by 0x4EC5AA8: std::__throw_logic_error(char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==28188==    by 0x4EFDA38: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==28188==    by 0x4EFDDDB: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==28188==    by 0x4022F3: main (main.cpp:13)
==28188== 
==28188== 144 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4 of 5
==28188==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28188==    by 0x4E9FF9F: __cxa_allocate_exception (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==28188==    by 0x4EC5A92: std::__throw_logic_error(char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==28188==    by 0x4EFDA38: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==28188==    by 0x4EFDDDB: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==28188==    by 0x4022F3: main (main.cpp:13)
```

It looks like ultimately the "conversion" (sorry again) new'ing a `std::string`.

If I change my code to this,

```
string d = string("/tmp");
Foo Foo = Foo(d);
```

Valgrind does not report the leak.

1. This is really a leak, right? Seems like it.
2. What's the proper idiom to do what I'm doing here? I want the call semantics to be able to pass a `char*` but internally I want the class member to be a `std::string`.

Comment: What is the type of `path` if it's a `std::string` there is no leak here.

Comment: Yes it's a `std::string`.

Comment: Then I don,t see how that constructor can leak.

Comment: Well, Valgrind seems to be saying this line new's a `std::string`, and no, I'm not free'ing that. Wouldn't that be the leak?

Comment: Look at `main.cpp:13`. You are probably constructing `std::string` with NULL `const char*` pointer, which leads to `std::logic_error` exception.

Comment: This seems like a mondo X/Y question since you're ignoring the glaring `logic_error` that gets thrown in there. Anyway, VTC because no MCVE.

Comment: Voted to close because no MCVE. However, re *"What's the proper idiom to do what I'm doing here?"* - In very new C++ code, consider: `Foo::Foo(std::string_view p): p(p) {}`. The data member should be `std::string`.

Comment: Oh, and actually, C++17 also has `std::filesystem::path`, which is preferable to representing a file path with a bare `std::string`, but unfortunately the new standard filesystem library is not yet fully supported by all major compilers.

Answer (score 3):

The Valgrind error that you're getting seems to suggest that your program terminated abnormally due to an exception. You can see this through the call stack: it looks like an internal `std::__throw_exception` function is getting called and that there's an object of type `std::logic_error` getting constructed. From context, it seems like what's happening here is that you passed an invalid argument into the `std::string` constructor, which then caused the `std::logic_error` to get thrown, causing a *different* `std::string` to get constructed and then thrown. Since the program terminated due to an exception, the destructors for the `std::string`s constructed this way never got called, hence the leak.

I'd run this program in `gdb` rather than `valgrind` to see if you can debug the source of the error. From what you've posted above I don't think we have enough context to provide any specific insights.

Comment: The program runs fine outside of Valgrind. I had assumed that Valgrind was terminating the program. Thanks I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Problem here is when you passed string literal which is actually of type const char * (c string) to const string , compiler creates temporary object by invoking overaloded ctor string(const char * ). This temporary object is then passed by value to Foo().
Temporary object of type string has internal allocation created something on heap and it should be freed when temporary object goes out of scope.
This is not definite memory leak but valgrind thinks (due to temp object doesnot have definite starting pointer pointing to it) in that way.
That's the reason it is reported as possbily lost (and not definitely lost).

Answer (score 1):

The idiom I like to use is Foo::Foo(const std::string &str)

Passes strings by reference, but also allows for string literals.

The one thing to look out for is a NULL char pointer.  That is quite possibly what you are seeing.